# Get multi array result as a list

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this code:

```
var people= ["jonh", "david", "brian", "paul", "martin", "scot", "steven", "george"];

var jonh= ["18", "male"];
var david = ["51", "male"];
var brian = ["13", "male"];
var paul = ["45", "male"];
var martin = ["10", "male"];
var scot = ["13", "male"];
var steven = ["15", "male"];
var george = ["20", "male"];

for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
var yearsOld= ???;
document.write(yearsOld + '<br>');
}
```

What do I need to put at ??? to get a list of the people´s age?

I tried something like `(people[i])[0]` but of course that wouldn´t work!

Help?

Comment: `window[people[i]][0]`, depending on your what scope you're in

Comment: Use an object instead of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the age data in an object like so:

```
var people = ["jonh", "david", "brian", "paul", "martin", "scot", "steven", "george"];

var data = {
  jonh: ["18", "male"],
  david: ["51", "male"],
  brian: ["13", "male"],
  paul: ["45", "male"],
  martin: ["10", "male"],
  scot: ["13", "male"],
  steven: ["15", "male"],
  george: ["20", "male"]
};

for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var person = people[i];
  var yearsOld = data[person][0];
  document.write(yearsOld + '<br>');
}
```